# Xamarin.Forms - Community Toolkit Popup working in iOS not Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have a bit of code that uses the Community Toolkit popup control. It works fine in iOS but no text is shown in Android. When I put a breakpoint, it does not appear to hit the breakpoint -- nor does it appear to hit other breakpoints.

```
var popup = new SwipePopUp
{
    CheckBoxText=CheckboxLabelText,
    GotItText=GotItText,
    CentralText=CentralText,
    Size=size
};
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ShowPopup(popup);
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining SwipePopUp? Where the code you shared is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have discovered that while iOS does not need OnPropertyChanged, Android does, and adding that fixed the problem.

Thanks!